# scope of the variable in dynamic SQL in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, dynamic-sql

I got this dynamic code:

```
declare @TableName varchar(100)='Customer'
declare @DestinationcolumnList  NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ServerName NVARCHAR(100) = '----'
DECLARE @SourceDatabase NVARCHAR(100) = 'Staging'
DECLARE @DestinationDatabase NVARCHAR(100) = 'History'
declare @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
set @SQL='
select  
        '+@DestinationcolumnList+' = coalesce('+@DestinationcolumnList+', '''') +'',''+ char(13) + char(10) + quotename(cast(d.COLUMN_NAME as varchar(128)))
from ['+@ServerName+'].['+@DestinationDatabase+'].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS d
inner join ['+@ServerName+'].['+@SourceDatabase+'].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS s 
        on d.TABLE_NAME = s.TABLE_NAME  
        and s.COLUMN_NAME = d.COLUMN_NAME
where   d.TABLE_NAME = '''+@TableName+'''
order by d.ORDINAL_POSITION
'
exec sp_executesql @SQL
select @DestinationcolumnList
```

its giving NULL value. when I execute same code without dynamic SQL its working fine. How scope of the variable works in dynamic SQL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DestinationcolumnList what value passing this variable

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @DestinationcolumnList containts column names from  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where ='Customer'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Dynamic SQL, variables declared outside the dynamic string are used to build a string, they are not used as a part of the string, so they cannot be used the way you are trying to do it: doing the undocumented trick of concatenating a variable with itself to produce a single string in a SELECT statement.

If you made the variable declaration part of the string, it should work:

```
set @SQL='
declare @DestinationcolumnList  NVARCHAR(MAX);

select  
        @DestinationcolumnList = coalesce(@DestinationcolumnList, '''') +'',''+ char(13) + char(10) + quotename(cast(d.COLUMN_NAME as varchar(128)))
from ['+@ServerName+'].['+@DestinationDatabase+'].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS d
inner join ['+@ServerName+'].['+@SourceDatabase+'].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS s 
        on d.TABLE_NAME = s.TABLE_NAME  
        and s.COLUMN_NAME = d.COLUMN_NAME
where   d.TABLE_NAME = '''+@TableName+'''
order by d.ORDINAL_POSITION;

select @DestinationcolumnList;
'

exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now I am able to get DestinationcolumnList values. can you please explain bit more about difference between declaring variable outside dynamic sql and inside dynamic sql. I am new to dynamic sql. Thanks.